# Поиск по году в БД

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq

Есть таблица со столбцом "Дата" формата 2018-03 в sql server.
Ввел в textBox год 2018
Как вывести в DataGridView все записи c таким годом?

Comment: Сделать выборку из базы данных с параметром год. Форматирование можно сделать как на сервере, так и на клиенте. `string.Format` - замечательно справляется с датами.

Comment: *со столбцом "Дата" формата 2018-03 в sql server* SQL Server не согласится принять дату без компоненты "день". *Как вывести в DataGridView все записи c таким годом?* Выполнив отбор в запросе по введённому значению. Либо выделив из даты год, либо составив из года начальную и конечную его даты.

Comment: @Akina я уже сделал, все работает.
Не знаете как сделать поиск по таблицам?
Допустим есть таблицы, каждая это число месяца и год (2018-03)
Как вывести в data grid значение всех таблиц которые содержат год который введу, например в текстбоксе 2018

Comment: @Akina Просто как я щас сделал мне не нравится, мне надо что бы данные которые я ввел, были в отдельной таблице, какой год и месяц такая и таблица создается у меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private void butFound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //поиск по году
        if(numericUpDownMonth.Value == 0)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select * From dbo.[{0}] Where YEAR(date) = {1}", MainWindow.currentDate, numericUpDownYear.Value), conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvArchive.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {//поиск по году и месяцу
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select * From dbo.[{0}] Where YEAR(date) = {1} and Month(date) = {2}", MainWindow.currentDate, numericUpDownYear.Value, numericUpDownMonth.Value), conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvArchive.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> таблица со столбцом "Дата" формата 2018-03

Это не "Дата". Это обычная строка

> Ввел в textBox год 2018

Если вам нужно искать по отдельным компонентам и компонента "день" у вас не предвидится, то разбейте это поле на два целочисленных "год"  и "месяц"

Comment: Тип date в таблице

Comment: @ne0n Тип `date` не может не содержать дня и не может быть в каком-то "формате"